# send message from Mapview.draw to activity

Tags: android, android-mapview, message, draw, onfling

I want to get the screen center when the map finally stops moving after a fling. I notice that there is no standard SDK event for this. I have seen a few techniques such as [override MapView.onTouchEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773717/android-maps-how-to-determine-map-center-after-a-drag-has-been-completed), or start a repeating timer on ACTION_UP and wait for end of map movement.

I am looking at overriding MapView.draw :-

```
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.draw(canvas);
    Log.e(TAG, "draw");
    center = this.getMapCenter();  //(GeoPoint)
    if (centerSave != null){
        if (centerSave.equals(center)){
            Log.e(TAG, "map stopped moving");
            // Now what goes here?????
        }
    }
    centerSave = center;
}
```

This "fling end" detection is a bit simpler then the others I have seen but it does maybe load the CPU a bit more since it runs on every draw.

I now want to send some kind of message/event to my MapActivity saying that the map has stopped moving. The MapActivity will then put a pushpin at the map center.

How do I send this message?

It is not messageing between threads, but between 2 different classes. There is probably a simple technique but the trick is to know it.

Thanks for any help

Peter

EDIT: I am using a handler to send a message to the UI thread. Unfortunately it is not solving the fling issue, (but it is an improvement).

```
// Now what goes here????
Message m = Message.obtain();
m.what = MyApplication.HANDLE_DRAW_TO;
MyApplication.tabbedMapActivityHandler.dispatchMessage(m);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using broadcasts!

Register a broadcastreceiver and dont forget to deregister the receiver in your onDestroy..

To create

```
 BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {         
            // if intent.getActiong equals "hello"
        }
    };
```

To send

```
 Intent broadcast = new Intent();
        broadcast.setAction("hello");
        sendBroadcast(broadcast);
```

To register (in ex onCreate)

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(BroadMess);
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

To deregister (in ex onDestroy)

```
unregisterReceiver(receiver);
```