# Get map center location while moving around

Tags: java, android, android-mapview, android-maps

I want to get the center coordinates of the map while the user is moving on it. I have to repopulate the map overlays depending on the current position of the map (the current center). Are there some listeners to listen on map panning or map moving? I know there is a `myMapView.getMapCenter()` method, but I have to call it from a listener, is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to handle the touch events on the UI in someway like the answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773717/android-maps-how-to-determine-map-center-after-a-drag-has-been-completed).

Comment: Thats great! you can always upvote and accept the answer of your question in order to help other people have the same issue.